# Rails - My 'create/new' method doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, crud, form-with

I've created a form so the user can add a new picture to the website catalog, but for some reasons it doesn't work. Once the form is filled out, I click on the 'Submit' button but nothing happens, I just stay on the same page (and I don't have any error message...).
I don't think the error comes from my Controller since nothing happens when I add the *raise* keyword in my Controller's 'create' method.

I'm sure this is an amateur mistake... but I can't see what it is. Thanks for your help!

**picture.rb** /
Picture model:

```
class Picture < ApplicationRecord
  validates :name, presence: true
  has_many_attached :photo
end
```

**new.html.erb** /
Here is my form :

```
<%= form_for(@picture) do |f| %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :name, "Please indicate the name" %>
    <%= f.text_field :name, class:"form-control", placeholder:"(mandatory field)" %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :description, "Add a description" %>
    <%= f.text_area :description, class:"form-control" %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <%= f.label :category, "Add a category" %>
        <%= f.text_field :category, class:"form-control" %>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <%= f.label :price, "Indicate the price (when applicable)" %>
        <%= f.number_field :price, class:"form-control", placeholder:"0,00$ CAD" %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <p>Where do you want to add this item?</p>
          <div>
            <%= f.check_box :is_home_item %>
            <%= f.label :is_home_item, "Homepage" %>
          </div>
          <div>
            <%= f.check_box :is_portfolio_item %>
            <%= f.label :is_portfolio_item, "Work" %>
          </div>
          <div>
            <%= f.check_box :is_sketchbook_item %>
            <%= f.label :is_sketchbook_item, "Sketchbook" %>
          </div>
        <div>
          <%= f.check_box :is_shopping_item %>
          <%= f.label :is_shopping_item, "Shopping" %>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.label :photo, "Select your picture" %>
          <%= f.file_field :photo, class:"form-control-file" %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.submit class:"btn btn-lg btn-primary" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**pictures_controller.rb** /

```
class PicturesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @picture = Picture.new
  end

  def create
    @picture = Picture.new(picture_params)
    if @picture.save
      redirect_to root_path(@picture), notice: "Picture was successfully created"
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private

  def picture_params
    params.require(:picture).permit(:name, :description, :category, :price, :is_home_item, :is_portfolio_item, :is_sketchbook_item, :is_shopping_item, :photo)
  end
end
```

[And here is the text I got on my local server console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9CjK.png)

Here is the HTML output of my form :

```
<form>
<input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="7MxWbzbltjXcAx2dvgRwIu07WMpyjPQji6LI6ELifMZODLJyMBucNApnPRk8vsjshSEjyMMenDUfvDw6pN+/4Q==">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="picture_name">Indicate the name</label>
    <input class="form-control" placeholder="(mandatory field)" type="text" name="picture[name]" id="picture_name">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="picture_description">Add a description</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" name="picture[description]" id="picture_description"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <label for="picture_category">Add a category</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="picture[category]" id="picture_category">
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <label for="picture_price">Indicate the price (when applicable)</label>
        <input class="form-control" placeholder="0,00$ CAD" type="number" name="picture[price]" id="picture_price">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <p>Where do you want to add your picture?</p>
          <div>
            <input name="picture[is_home_item]" type="hidden" value="0"><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="picture[is_home_item]" id="picture_is_home_item">
            <label for="picture_is_home_item">Homepage</label>
          </div>
          <div>
            <input name="picture[is_portfolio_item]" type="hidden" value="0"><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="picture[is_portfolio_item]" id="picture_is_portfolio_item">
            <label for="picture_is_portfolio_item">Work</label>
          </div>
          <div>
            <input name="picture[is_sketchbook_item]" type="hidden" value="0"><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="picture[is_sketchbook_item]" id="picture_is_sketchbook_item">
            <label for="picture_is_sketchbook_item">Sketchbook</label>
          </div>
        <div>
          <input name="picture[is_shopping_item]" type="hidden" value="0"><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="picture[is_shopping_item]" id="picture_is_shopping_item">
          <label for="picture_is_shopping_item">Shopping</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="picture_photo">Select your picture</label>
          <input class="form-control-file" type="file" name="picture[photo]" id="picture_photo">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Create Picture" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" data-disable-with="Create Picture">
  </div>
```

**My routes :**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  
  # Pages routes
  root to: 'pages#home'
  get 'about', to: 'pages#about'
  get 'portfolio', to: 'pages#portfolio'
  get 'sketchbook', to: 'pages#sketchbook'
  get 'shopping', to: 'pages#shopping'
  
  # Pictures routes
  resources :pictures

end
```

[And these are my routes in the Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yedul.png)

Comment: Change `<%= form_for(@picture) do |f| %>` to `<%= form_for(@picture, local: true) do |f| %>`.

Comment: Thanks @sam but unfortunately it doesn't work :/

Comment: Hmm... you might want to change `form_for` to `form_with(model: @picture`. If that doesn't work, what does it say in console when you click submit?

Comment: It still doesn't work :/ I added at the end of my original message a screenshot of the text I got on my local server console

Comment: Okay. So it's making a GET request to pictures#new. You need it to make a PUT request to pictures#create. My guess now is that one of two things is going on. You either have your routes configured wrong (they should be `resources :pictures`) or for some reason your form_with is not defaulting to a post method with the right action. Can you add the html output of your form? You can strip out the authenticity token part, just the line that starts `<form`. And also your routes line(s) for pictures.

Comment: Oh ok, it makes sense. I added the HTML output and the routes in my first message. The routes seem ok to me, I'm not sure why it triggers a GET request instead of a POST

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite sure why this is happening, but `form_for` is deprecated, so you should replace it with `form_with`.

You can use a model, such as your `@picture` with form_with as described in [the docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#binding-a-form-to-an-object).

```
<%= form_with(model: @picture) do |form| %>
  # fields
<% end %>
```

This should create a form DOM object that looks like this:

```
<form action="/pictures" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8" >
  <input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="..." />
  ...
</form>
```

If for some reason it doesn't, you can always pass a `method: :post` in the form_with (ie. `<%= form_with(model: @picture, method: :post) do |form| %>`).

Comment: Again thanks for your help Sam!

Actually I already tried that but it doesn't work. Do you think it could be a database issue (instead of a coding issue) ? Something to do with ActiveRecords or Active Storage  maybe ? I'm wondering if I set up my database correctly...

Comment: I don't think so. Right now your issue is the GET request. You need to get that part solved. You could try removing the photo and just see if you can save the name, though. Also in the console run `Picture.create!(name: 'Test Picture')` to make sure there's no DB issue.

Comment: I tried that in the console and it worked. So you were right, the issue was somewhere else.
As mentioned by Ayushi in her comment, the problem was coming from my Picture model. I updated it and my `picture_params` method and it's now working.
Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you have got `has_many_attached` with a singular `photo`. That does not seem to be the right syntax. Have you tried changing to `has_many_attached :photos` and modifying the `picture_params` to have photos passed as an array `photos: []`?

Or if you wanted to attach one photo, then you should try changing to `has_one_attached :photo` in the Picture model.

Comment: It worked! I updated the Picture model with `has_many_attached :photos` and also  modified the `picture_params` to have photos passed as an array `photos: []` and it seems to be working.
Thanks so much for your help Ayushi :)